# Modify a char * in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I'm doing a project for school and I must use char * intead of string.
I need to modify some parts of the char * but every time I try I have memory issues.

The name has this format: "1.1.2" and what I want to do is return a c* that contains "1.1.3" so I need to get the last char from the name and make a +1.

This is part of the code:

```
struct ve
{
     char * name;
};

char * modificar(ve *v)
{
    char *c= new char(strlen(v->name)+1);
    //I don't know what to do here to get the results I want
    return c; 
}
```

Comment: A little more effort, please. You *do* know what to do there -- you say so above.

Comment: You need to use the array allocation new char[] with square brackets.

Comment: Do you need to make the last char literally 3 or do you need to add 1 to whatever the last char happens to be?

Comment: I know what I want to do, but when I try it gets error. I need to add 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very basic approach to do exactly what you asked is outlined below:

```
char *c = strdup(v->name);
c[strlen(c)-1]++;
return c;
```

However, it has problems for things like 1.1.9, which requires quite a bit more complicated logic.

Comment: I suspect you mean `strdup` instead of `strcpy`.

Comment: Great catch -- thank you!  Too little C in my life. :(

Comment: Won't work if the caller is expecting to `delete` the returned value